# Log4Net - Create an Smtpappender programmatically

Tags: smtp, log4net, appender

I am a beginner in log4net and I am trying to add an appender in my code and then to send an email in case of an Error. I don't want to use a config file. My program runs but I never receive the email. What's wrong in my code?

```
Dim test2 As log4net.Appender.SmtpAppender = New log4net.Appender.SmtpAppender()
test2.To = toto@hotmail.com
test2.From = toto@hotmail.com
test2.Subject = "test Email report"
test2.SmtpHost = "localhost"
test2.BufferSize = 1
test2.Lossy = true

Dim layout As log4net.Layout.PatternLayout = New log4net.Layout.PatternLayout()
layout.ConversionPattern = "%newline%message"
test2.Layout = layout
test2.ActivateOptions()


Dim l As log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("EmailLog").Logger
l.Level = log4net.Core.Level.Error
l.Additivity = True
l.Repository.Configured = True
l.AddAppender(test2)


msg = "test test test" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine


Dim logger As log4net.ILog = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("EmailLog")
logger.Error(msg)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a direct answer to your question, but a useful suggestion.
Test it using the configuration setup first, that way you can quickly eliminate any external problems unrelated to your code.